# How to make submenus appear on hover regardless of what page you are on?

Tags: theming

I am using CorporateClean theme for this [site](http://joanholt.tk) and I want the submenus dropping down from the main menu tab "gallery" to appear on hover no matter which page you are on. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your Menu Link and make sure **Show as expanded** is checked.

> If selected and this menu link has children, the menu will always
>   appear expanded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I neglected to have show as expanded on main link.